# Can't detect <3 in a php string?

Tags: php, text-processing

I am basically processing tweets for a project of mine. I am trying to separate the emoticons, if any and storing them in a separate array (removing them from the tweet which shall be processed further). No matter what I try, I just can't seem to detect <3 in the string. Neither str_replace() nor preg_replace() seem to work.

I believe there is something wrong because of the '<' symbol, a substr_count($str, '<') always returns a 0.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code including example input.

Comment: Are you sure it's a real `<` and not just a `&lt;` your browser is "helpfully" displaying as as `<`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Twitter API always sends `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;` for security purposes. (The motivation is to make it safe for you to display tweets on a webpage without worrying about sanitizing them yourself to avoid XSS attacks).